# convert a program with ADT methods python

Tags: python, class

I am a beginning programmer.

I've been writing codes on a mastermind solver in the six-guess algorithm for an assignment.

(More info on mastermind and its algorithms:[Mastermind on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29))

And I figured it out days ago. But our prof set the fixed template, and then I don't know how to convert my codes into it.

Below is my code. May be awkward but it works and it's not that slow.

---

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [list(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield list(prod)

def sort_list(total_list):
    d0=list()
    d1=list()
    d2=list()
    d3=list()
    d4=list()

    for x in total_list:
        mlist=list()
        alist = x
        n = 0
        while n<4:
            m = alist.count(alist[n])
            mlist.append(m)
            n = n + 1
        if max(mlist)==1:
            d0.append(alist)
        elif max(mlist)==2 and mlist.count(2)==2:
            d1.append(alist)
        elif max(mlist)==2 and mlist.count(2)>2:
            d2.append(alist)
        elif max(mlist)==3 :
            d3.append(alist)
        elif max(mlist)==4 :
            d4.append(alist)

    total_list = d0+d1+d2+d3+d4
    possible = [''.join(p) for p in total_list]
    return total_list

def computeFeedback(code,guess):    
    b = 0
    w = 0
    inCodeCount = {'A':0,'B':0,'C':0,'D':0, 'E':0, 'F':0}
    inGuessCount = {'A':0,'B':0,'C':0,'D':0, 'E':0, 'F':0}
    for i in range(0,4):
        if code[i] == guess[i]:
            b += 1
        inCodeCount[code[i]]+=1
        inGuessCount[guess[i]]+=1
    for ch in inCodeCount:
        w+=min(inCodeCount [ch], inGuessCount [ch])
    w-=b 
    feedback = str(w)+'w'+str(b)+'b'
    return feedback

guesscount=0
code=input()
while guesscount<8:
    guesscount += 1
    if guesscount==1:
        guess='ABCD'
        print("My guess is:",guess)
        feedback=computeFeedback(code,guess)
        if feedback!='0w4b':
            combinations=sort_list([''.join(x) for x in product('ABCDEF',repeat=4)])
            overlap=list()
            for x in combinations:
                fb=computeFeedback(guess,x)
                overlap.append(x)
                if fb != feedback:
                    overlap.pop()
            common=overlap
            overlap=list()

        else:
            print("Game Over in", guesscount,"steps")
            break
    if guesscount==2:
        guess='BCDE'
        print("My guess is:",guess)
        feedback=computeFeedback(code,guess)
        if feedback!='0w4b':
            combinations=sort_list([''.join(x) for x in product('ABCDEF',repeat=4)])
            overlap=list()
            for x in combinations:
                fb=computeFeedback(guess,x)
                overlap.append(x)
                if fb != feedback:
                    overlap.pop()
            common=[token for token in overlap if token in common]
            overlap=list()

        else:
            print('Game Over in,', guesscount,'steps')
            break
    if guesscount==3:
        guess='CDEF'
        print("My guess is:",guess)
        feedback=computeFeedback(code,guess)
        if feedback!='0w4b':
            combinations=sort_list([''.join(x) for x in product('ABCDEF',repeat=4)])
            overlap=list()
            for x in combinations:
                fb=computeFeedback(guess,x)
                overlap.append(x)
                if fb != feedback:
                    overlap.pop()
            common=[token for token in overlap if token in common]

            overlap=list()
        else:
            print('Game Over in', guesscount,'steps')
            break
    if guesscount==4:
        if common[0]=="acfb".upper():
            guess="dcad".upper()
        if common[0]=="aebf".upper():
            guess="edfd".upper()
        if common[0]=='AEFB':
            guess='EACC'
        if common[0]=='AFBE':
            guess='BFCD'
        if common[0]=='BAFE':
            guess='EADC'
        if common[0]=='BEAF':
            guess='EDAE'
        if common[0]=='BEFA':
            guess='EEDA'
        if common[0]=='EABF':
            guess='FDFB'
        if common[0]=='AADB':
            guess='BABD'
        if common[0]=='ABAE':
            guess='BBCC'
        if common[0]=='AEAF':
            guess='CFFD'
        if common[0]=='CAFA':
            guess='FDFA'
        if common[0]=='AAEE':
            guess='DDDF'
        else:
            guess=common[0]
        print("My guess is:",guess)
        if len(common)>1:
            common.pop(0)

            feedback=computeFeedback(code,guess)
            if feedback!='0w4b':
                combinations=sort_list([''.join(x) for x in product('ABCDEF',repeat=4)])
                overlap=list()
                for x in combinations:
                    fb=computeFeedback(guess,x)
                    overlap.append(x)
                    if fb != feedback:
                        overlap.pop()
                common=[token for token in overlap if token in common]
                overlap=list()
            else:
                print('Game Over in', guesscount,'steps')
                break
        else:
            print('Game Over in', guesscount,'steps') 
            break
    if guesscount==5:
        guess=common[0]
        print("My guess is:",guess)
        if len(common)>1:
            common.pop(0)

            feedback=computeFeedback(code,guess)
            if feedback!='0w4b':
                combinations=sort_list([''.join(x) for x in product('ABCDEF',repeat=4)])
                overlap=list()
                for x in combinations:
                    fb=computeFeedback(guess,x)
                    overlap.append(x)
                    if fb != feedback:
                        overlap.pop()
                common=[token for token in overlap if token in common]

                overlap=list()
            else:
                print('Game Over in', guesscount,'steps')
                break
        else:
            print('Game Over in', guesscount,'steps')
            break
    if guesscount==6:
            guess=common[0]
            print("My guess is:",guess)
            if len(common)>1:
                common.pop(0)

                feedback=computeFeedback(code,guess)
                if feedback!='0w4b':
                    combinations=sort_list([''.join(x) for x in product('ABCDEF',repeat=4)])
                    overlap=list()
                    for x in combinations:
                        fb=computeFeedback(guess,x)
                        overlap.append(x)
                        if fb != feedback:
                            overlap.pop()
                    common=[token for token in overlap if token in common]

                    overlap=list()
                else:
                    print('Game Over in', guesscount,'steps')
                    break
            else:
                print('Game Over in', guesscount,'steps')
                break
    if guesscount==7:
            guess=common[0]
            print("My guess is:",guess)
            if len(common)>1:
                common.pop(0)
                feedback=computeFeedback(code,guess)
                if feedback!='0w4b':
                    combinations=sort_list([''.join(x) for x in product('ABCDEF',repeat=4)])
                    overlap=list()
                    for x in combinations:
                        fb=computeFeedback(guess,x)
                        overlap.append(x)
                        if fb != feedback:
                            overlap.pop()
                    common=[token for token in overlap if token in common]

                    overlap=list()
                else:
                    print('Game Over in', guesscount,'steps')
                    break
            else:
                print('Game Over in', guesscount,'steps')
                break
if guesscount==8:
    print('Failure')
```

---

Yeah, and here comes the template for both the code-breaker function I have to complete and a mastermind engine to run the function:

---

Template

```
class CodeBreaker:
    def __init__(self):



    def makeGuess(self):

        return guess

    def getFeedback(self, feedbackStr):
```

---

Engine

```
from mastermind import CodeBreaker

def computeFeedback(code,guess):
    # Given a code and guess computes the feedback string

    b = 0
    w = 0
    inCodeCount = {'A':0,'B':0,'C':0,'D':0, 'E':0, 'F':0}
    inGuessCount = {'A':0,'B':0,'C':0,'D':0, 'E':0, 'F':0}
    for i in range(0,4):
        if code[i] == guess [i]:
            b += 1
        inCodeCount[code[i]] += 1
        inGuessCount[guess[i]] += 1
    for ch in inCodeCount:
        w += min(inCodeCount [ch], inGuessCount [ch])
    w -= b 
    feedback = str(w)+'w'+str(b)+'b'
    return feedback

code = input()

while (code != None):
    guesscount = 0
    myBreaker = CodeBreaker()
    while (guesscount < 8):
        guess = myBreaker.makeGuess()
        print("My guess is:",guess)
        guesscount += 1
        feedback = computeFeedback(code, guess)
        print(feedback)
        if feedback == "0w4b":
            print("Game Over in", guesscount,"steps")
            break
        myBreaker.getFeedback(feedback)
    if guesscount == 8:
        print("Failed to find the solution in 8 steps")
    code = input()
```

---

I'm bad at Classes. I've even no idea on what's the **init** should contain. Anyone could help?

Thanks so much!

Comment: The `__init__` method is called the initialisator - it initializes a class after it has been instantiated (constructed). It doesn't _need_ to contain anything, unless you need it to do initialization work necessary for every instance of that class.

Comment: Syntactically speaking, `__init__`'s definition must contain *something*, but that something may be the single no-op statement `pass`.

Comment: @LukasGraf Thanks first, and sorry for I didn't make it clear.I understrand what __init__ does.But just don't know what should I initialize in my code.In the getFeedback template, I made a list denoted as 'overlap'to store possibilities of codes, and then create a new list called 'common' to store the information. But if I initialize the common list and the overlap list as an empty list, every time that I call them in the getfeedback method, both lists are empty, therefore I lost the information that I need for the next step in the loop. How can I store and pass the information?

Comment: @larsmans Absolutely correct. What I meant to say was "an `__init__` method doesn't need to be present".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to convert your code into a class is to put all your code into the `getFeedback` method, except that instead of computing a guess which you send off to be evaluated, remember the guess in the property `self.guess`, and return that next time the `makeGuess` function is called. You'll also want to turn all your global variables (like `common`) into properties (like `self.common`). Here's a sketch:

```
class CodeBreaker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.guess_count = 0
        self.guess = 'ABCD'
        self.common = []

    def makeGuess(self):
        return self.guess

    def getFeedback(self, feedback):
        self.guess_count += 1
        if self.guess_count == 1:
            # ... your code here ...
            self.guess = 'BCDE'
        elif self.guess_count == 2:
            # ... your code here ...
            self.guess = 'CDEF'
        elif self.guess_count == 3:
            # ... your code here ...
        # ... and so on ...
```

I should add that your code is very repetitive. The following changes would be worthwhile:

1. The Python standard library already contains a function [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) that does the job of your function `product` (though it takes its arguments in a different way), so you might as well use that instead.
2. You copy out essentially the same code for each guess (generating the set of combinations, evaluating the combinations against the most recent guess, updating `common` and so on). It should be straightforward to put this code into a method so that you don't have to copy it out so many times.
3. The code for guesses number 4 and higher is almost identical: surely there's no need to copy out this code at all (just write `if guesscount >= 4:` and handle them all at the same time).

You might want to study this class (which uses a similar method to your solution, but with all the repetition cut out) and see if you can figure out how it works:

```
from itertools import product
from random import choice
from copy import copy

class CodeBreaker(object):
    all_codes = [''.join(c) for c in product(*['ABCDEF'] * 4)]

    def __init__(self):
        self.codes = copy(self.all_codes)
        self.guess = 'AABB'     # Best first guess!

    def makeGuess(self):
        return self.guess

    def getFeedback(self, feedback):
        self.codes = [c for c in self.codes if computeFeedback(c, self.guess) == feedback]
        self.guess = choice(self.codes)
```

This algorithm can take up to eight guesses in the worst case, but you have eight guesses available, so that's OK. If you had only six guesses available, then you'd need a cleverer approach. The following alternative algorithm makes the best guess based on one move of lookahead, and needs at most six guesses. (It runs very slowly, however!) Again, you might find it interesting to study how it works (hint: it takes the [minimum of a list of maxima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax)).

```
    def getFeedback(self, feedback):
        self.codes = [c for c in self.codes if computeFeedback(c, self.guess) == feedback]
        def key(g): return max(Counter(computeFeedback(c, g) for c in self.codes).values())
        self.guess = min(self.codes, key = key)
```

And here's [Knuth's five-guess algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29#Five-guess_algorithm) (which runs even slower):

```
    def getFeedback(self, feedback):
        self.codes = [c for c in self.codes if computeFeedback(c, self.guess) == feedback]
        if len(self.codes) == 1:
            self.guess = self.codes[0]
        else:
            def key(g): return max(Counter(computeFeedback(c, g) for c in self.codes).values())
            self.guess = min(self.all_codes, key = key)
```

P.S. Your professor's code isn't perfect, either! Apart from not following conventional Python style (see [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), it also seems rather complex and long-winded. Why not take advantage of Python's [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) class to write something short and simple:

```
from collections import Counter

def computeFeedback(code, guess):
    """
    Return the string `{white}w{black}b` where `black` is a count of the
    characters in `guess` that appear at the same position in `code`
    and `white` is a count of the characters in `guess` that appear at
    a different position in `code`.

    >>> computeFeedback('ABCD', 'ACAD')
    '1w2b'
    >>> computeFeedback('ABAB', 'AABB')
    '2w2b'
    >>> computeFeedback('ABCD', 'DCBA')
    '4w0b'
    """
    w = sum((Counter(code) & Counter(guess)).values())
    b = sum(c == g for c, g in zip(code, guess))
    return '{}w{}b'.format(w - b, b)
```

Comment: Thanks! It's useful and I finally know how the Knuth's algorithm works!